# Compile issues based on different platforms

Tags: .net, c++, exception, compilation, unhandled

I'm compiling a solution which runs fine on the PC but when trying to compile it for a different platform I get the following error:

"Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added."

Anyone know what it could mean?

Comment: you are trying to complie or trying to run?

Comment: Looks like a run-time error not a compiler message, and therefore not likely to be a code error.  What were you running when this occurred? i.e. what process is the exception associated with?

Comment: And what is this "different platform"?  It looks to me like it might come from .NET, which is on the PC.  Which compilers are you using?  Do you get that message on compilation or (which looks more likely) on running?

Comment: When I tried to start my car yesterday, it woudn't start. Any idea what that could mean?

We need to know exactly what's happening before we can say what the problem is. What exactly are you doing? What does your code look like, and do you get the code when you compile or run your project? If it is when you compile, then how do you compile it?
We're programmers, not psychics. We can't read your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a .NET exception message.  Hmm, you definitely tagged it as C++.  I'd guess you found a bug in your IDE or whatever tool you use to build your project.

Comment: or he's writing a C++/CLI project, and neglected to tell us ;)

Answer (score 0):

Googling the error comes up with one mention of VB assemblies with classes that differ only in case (like, say, GetLine vs. Getline).  This is perfectly legitimate in C++, but might not work on .NET or other frameworks.

I've found that copy-pasting error codes or large chunks of error messages into a Google search to be very usefu.